# Please help me understand this - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Can someone please explain how this works? Like, how does it count?

```
for a in range(2,5): 
    for b in range(1,2): 
        print (a+b,end=" ")
    print("---",end=" ")
```

the output is: 3 --- 4 --- 5 ---

Comment: can you show ur output.

Answer (score 2):

It just adds 2, 3, 4 with 1 and prints the result.

In Python-3.x, `print()` is a function and the argument `end` in it means

> string appended after the last value, default a newline

Values returned by `range(x, y)` are `[x, y-1]`

If you don't know the usage of a function, you could open [ipython](http://ipython.org/) and type something like the following:

```
help(print)
help(range)
```